# Is there a natural intuitive interpretation of the **numerical value** of the coefficients of risk aversion?

Tags: utility, preferences, expected-utility, risk-aversion

We can write down the **coefficient of absolute risk aversion** $R_a$, or the **coefficient of relative risk aversion** $R_r$.

**Are there intuitive interpretations of the numerical values of these coefficients? Let's say that someone has $R_a=5$ or $R_r=3$ for certain wealth level $W$, how would we interpret that number?**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is such an interpretation in Section 3 of the original paper by Pratt:

> Pratt, J. (1964). [Risk Aversion in the Small and in the Large](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1913738).
>   Econometrica, 32(1/2), 122-136.

Under some regularity conditions, the coefficient of absolute risk aversion approximates the risk premium divided by half the variance for a small actuarily fair gamble. In Pratt's words, "$r(x)$ is twice the risk premium per unit of variance for infinitesimal risks". A similar interpretation holds for relative risk aversion, see Section 10.

Comment: I see. So I assume that for constant absolute risk aversion, the principle holds for non-infinitessimal risks as well? Could you post the interpretation of relative risk aversion, if you want to (not if you don't want to of course)?

Comment: I'll adress the relative risk aversion case tomorrow. One of the regularity assumptions is that the third moments become relatively negligible in comparison to the variance. So I don't think one can apply this to large gambles even under CARA.